# Distance from points to points in the same polygon

Tags: python, qgis-3, proximity, connection

I have 2 point layers and 1 polygon layer. I want to find distance nearest between this 2 point layer, but they must be in the same polygons.

I used distance nearest hub, NNJoin, MMQgis but they just have take part in of 2 layer, there are no conditions attached.

Apart from these tools, are there any tools or python or any way to solve this problem?